# Google Analytics 4 has different number for Revenue comparing to Google Play and App Store connect in total or separately

Tags: google-analytics, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect, google-analytics-4

The total Revenue that Google Analytics 4 is showing to me for the same period of time is less than the Revenue which Google Play dashboard shows. It also shows less revenue comparing to app store connect. Its numbers are less for all days if I check the daily numbers.
The second problem that I have while working with GA4 is the incorrect number for app_store_subscription_renew which I dont know why is it different?